# How to interact with current running command cell in google colab?

Tags: terminal, jupyter-notebook, google-colaboratory

Here what the cell looks like

```
Cloning into 'XYZ'...
The authenticity of host 'github.com (192.**.###.113)' can't be established.
RSA key fingerprint is SHA256:nThbg6kXUpJIGOCWGl7E1spRomTxdCARLviKw6E5SY8.
Are you sure you want to continue connecting (yes/no)?
```

How to give yes or no to this running command cell?

Answer (score 2):

There's no easy way to interact with the process once it's running; two options:

1. Pass `yes` to the program from the shell, eg `echo 'yes' | git ...` or just `y | git ...` (if `y` works as a response).
2. If possible, clone via an `https` path instead of a `git` one.

Answer (score 2):

Passing "-y" or "--yes" along with the command works.

For example:

!pip uninstall lightgbm --yes

Comment: This does not work with all CLIs, git clone does not accept --yes

Answer (score 0):

I made a code line after the question and then typed: --y

it worked!